# Why is my scoped lock faster than a manual lock?

Tags: c++

In [this code sample](http://ideone.com/amQK5) I benchmark scoped vs manual locking of a pthread mutex. I expected equal perfomance for both approaches. But much to my surprise the scoped lock solution seems a little faster.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

I'm using using g++ 4.5.2 and compile with the following options:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -O2 -o test main.cpp
```

#### Update

When doing 2 billion iterations on my local PC (not Ideone) I get a larger difference:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -O2 -o test main.cpp
scoped_lock: 10530ms
normal: 11290ms
scoped_lock: 10530ms
normal: 11280ms
scoped_lock: 10530ms
normal: 11280ms
scoped_lock: 10530ms
normal: 11290ms
```

#### Update 2

I improved the program with a higher resolution clock: http://ideone.com/CMbuw. This time the scoped lock is a little slower.

I think it's safe to conclude that it's a measuring anomaly.

Comment: That's a difference <5%. It might be a measuring anomaly.

Comment: Looks like a measurement error. When I change the iteration count to 50 millions results become identical.

Comment: You can take that difference or leave it - basically, it's a "measuring error". There should be virtually no difference between the two approaches..

Comment: Curious - the assembly code of the two functions is perfectly identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [changed the iteration count to 50 millions](http://ideone.com/yx9Lx) (was 20 millions in your code) and the results are now

```
result: Time limit exceeded     time: 5s    memory: 2828 kB     signal: 24 (SIGXCPU)
input: no
output:
scoped_lock: 740ms
normal: 740ms
scoped_lock: 710ms
normal: 710ms
scoped_lock: 720ms
normal: 720ms
```

perfectly identical. So I'd blame measurement errors in your test case - just not enough iterations of code. If you really care you should look into emitted machine code.

Comment: For Ideone I had to make the test short enough or else the process gets killed. I compared the assembly on my computer and it's indeed identical.

Comment: Sorry for un-accepting your answer. Even though I thought the assembly output looked identical I do get a larger time difference when increasing the iteration count. I would still like to understand why that is.

Comment: Apparently it was just some randomness.

Answer (score 0):

For such a small difference, I recommend that you read the generated assembly code. Perhaps the compiler is able to squeeze out a couple of instructions for the scope-based approach, that need to be there when doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Preemptive, multitasking operating systems allocate processor time to individual processes. (IANA OS programmer, so please correct me) On Windows processes are (used to be?) given a 'slice' of 60ms run time. At the end of each slice, or earlier if a process voluntarily gives up its slice by waiting, if there is another process waiting for the CPU, the first process is put to sleep and the second one is given a slice. If there are no processes ready to run then the first process gets another go straight away.

Basically, if you are running any non-trivial timing tests, any differences less than a few slices are insignificant.